# how can my app modify the shop's template files

Tags: shopify

I need to inject liquid markup to the store's theme templates when my app is installed. I know there are ScriptTags, but they load scripts. And I know that the scripts can change the page's DOM. but I need to install my liquid to the product details pages. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add your Liquid as a new snippet asset. The merchant can then be instructed to paste a  Liquid include statement you provide them in their product Liquid scripts.

That is fairly clean. Otherwise, your App could download their product Liquid script, edit it, and then add it to the shop as an alternative template. You could then instruct the merchant to render their products with the alternative template.

I am sure there are other possibilities too.

Comment: Thank you David. I tried this app on my test shop and it changed my templates automatically: http://spinstudioapp.com/ How do they do it?

Comment: As I mentioned, you are free to download any template, edit it, and then transfer it with your edits back to the shop. Perhaps they do that. It is probably not the nicest thing to do. Merchants are left scratching their heads about how to undo the changes.