# want to replace {{ variable | filter }} or warp this value with some html tag

Tags: php, shopify

1. <P> {{ variable | money_with_currency }} </P>
2. <P> {{variable1 | money }}   something </P>
3. <div> {{ variable | filter}}   </div>
4. <P><b class="xyz"> {{ variable | filter }} </b></P>

output:

1. <P><b class="xyz"> {{ variable | money_with_currency }} </b></P>
2. <P> {{ variable1 | money }} something </P>
3. <div><b class="xyz"> {{ variable | filter }} </b></div>
4. <P><b class="xyz"> {{ variable | filter }} </b></P>

I want to wrap when variable find between the {{ }} but if it is already wrap than no need to wrap for 2nd time.

in my case I want to wrap if {{ }} has "variable" and wrap with

<b class="xyz"> 
{{ inner statement that not change only check for existence }} </b>

line 1 we need to wrap this one and see in the output

line 2 we no need to wrap because {{ }} has variable 1 which is differ

line 3 we need to wrap {{ }} has variable

line 4 we no need to wrap because it is already wrap with

Comment: Post whatever code you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help if regular expression, you can create a pattern and perform a non-greedy search on your string and replace each match with added wrappers for each match.

```
function wrapVariables($subject,$opening_tags,$closing_tags){
    $matches = [];

    preg_match_all("/\{\{.*\}\}/U",$subject,$matches);

    $map_for_matches = [];

    foreach($matches[0] as $each_match){
        if(!isset($map_for_matches[$each_match])){
            $replace_value = $opening_tags . $each_match . $closing_tags;
            $subject = str_replace($each_match,$replace_value, $subject);
            $map_for_matches[$each_match] = 1;
        }    
    }

   return $subject;
}

$subject = "<P> {{ variable | money_with_currency }} </P><P> {{variable | money }} something </P><P> {{ variable | filter}} </P><P> {{variable | filter}} </P><P> {{ variable | money_with_currency }} </P>";

echo wrapVariables($subject,"<b class='xyz'>","</b>");
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<P> <b class='xyz'>{{ variable | money_with_currency }}</b> </P>
<P> <b class='xyz'>{{variable | money }}</b> something </P>
<P> <b class='xyz'>{{ variable | filter}}</b> </P>
<P> <b class='xyz'>{{variable | filter}}</b> </P>
<P> <b class='xyz'>{{ variable | money_with_currency }}</b> </P>
```

**UPDATE**

Regex patterns match `<p>` and `<b>` tags specifically since you haven't mentioned what would be the scope of the text.

Here, regex pattern first matches `<p>` tags-> filters each of them-> performs pattern matching of `variable` on each filter keeping track of already added `wrappers` such as `<b class='xyz'></b>`.

```
<?php

function wrapVariables($subject,$opening_tags,$closing_tags,$variable_to_replace){
    $new_subject = "";
    $matches = [];

    preg_match_all("/<[pP]>(<.+>)?.+(<\/.+>)?<\/[pP]>/U",$subject,$matches);

    foreach($matches[0] as $each_match){
        $new_matches = [];
        preg_match_all("/(<b class='xyz'>)?\\s*\{\{[^\\w]*".$variable_to_replace."[^\\w].*\}\}\\s*(<\/b>)?/U",$each_match,$new_matches);
        if(!empty($new_matches[0][0]) && empty($new_matches[1][0])) $new_subject .= str_replace($new_matches[0][0],$opening_tags . $new_matches[0][0] . $closing_tags,$each_match);
        else $new_subject .= $each_match;
    }

    return $new_subject;
}

$subject = "<P> {{ variable | money_with_currency }} </P><P> <b class='xyz'> {{ variable| money_with_currency }} </b></P><P> {{ |variable| money_with_currency }} </P><P> <b class='xyz'> {{ |variable money_with_currency }} </b></P><P> {{ variable | filter }} </P><P><b class='xyz'>{{ variable | filter }}</b></P><P>{{ InnervariableInner | money_with_currency }} </P><P> {{variablePrefix | money_with_currency }} </P><P> {{Suffixvariable| money_with_currency }} </P><P>{{Suffixvariable| money_with_currency }}</P><P> {{ variable2 | money_with_currency }} </P><P> {{ variable9 | money_with_currency }} </P>";

echo wrapVariables($subject,"<b class='xyz'>","</b>","variable");
```

**INPUT**

```
<P> {{ variable | money_with_currency }} </P>
<P> <b class='xyz'> {{ variable| money_with_currency }} </b></P>
<P> {{ |variable| money_with_currency }} </P>
<P> <b class='xyz'> {{ |variable money_with_currency }} </b></P>
<P> {{ variable | filter }} </P>
<P><b class='xyz'>{{ variable | filter }}</b></P>
<P>{{ InnervariableInner | money_with_currency }} </P>
<P> {{variablePrefix | money_with_currency }} </P>
<P> {{Suffixvariable| money_with_currency }} </P>
<P>{{Suffixvariable| money_with_currency }}</P>
<P> {{ variable2 | money_with_currency }} </P>
<P> {{ variable9 | money_with_currency }} </P>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<P><b class='xyz'> {{ variable | money_with_currency }}</b> </P>
<P> <b class='xyz'> {{ variable| money_with_currency }} </b></P>
<P><b class='xyz'> {{ |variable| money_with_currency }}</b> </P>
<P> <b class='xyz'> {{ |variable money_with_currency }} </b></P>
<P><b class='xyz'> {{ variable | filter }}</b> </P>
<P><b class='xyz'>{{ variable | filter }}</b></P>
<P>{{ InnervariableInner | money_with_currency }} </P>
<P> {{variablePrefix | money_with_currency }} </P>
<P> {{Suffixvariable| money_with_currency }} </P>
<P>{{Suffixvariable| money_with_currency }}</P>
<P> {{ variable2 | money_with_currency }} </P>
<P> {{ variable9 | money_with_currency }} </P>
```

Comment: would  you please give the best tutorial link for learning regular expression the only think is very difficult to make regexp...

Comment: if I have {{ variable }} and {{ variable1 }} and i want to wrap only for {{ variable }} and also check for already wrap or not if already wrap than no need to wrapping more..

Comment: It will wrap only once for a particular match. That is the reason I had to create `$map_for_matches`.To test this,  I deliberately added `{{ variable | money_with_currency }}` twice in my `$subject` variable and it works just fine(as you can see in the output). Also, can you a bit  more clear about `variable` and `variable1`? Perhaps, can give me exact names of those variables? 

Also, you can learn regex from [here](https://regexone.com/) and practice [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/regex/re-introduction)

Comment: variable1 and variable.. etc  is different variable name which present same time in my string and want to replace for some specific variable for e.g 'bla bala {{ item.price }} bla bla bla bla...{{ item.name }}' and want to wrap only item.price so out put will be 'bla bala <b> {{ item.price }} </b> bla bla bla bla...{{ item.name }}' .
if item.price is multiple time it will be wrap with tag but no need to all other variable 
Hope it make sense (my English is not well )

Comment: I changed the question for elaborate

Comment: thanks. The <p> is not fix it would be any tag with many attribute class,id, etc.., the thing is fix is only {{ * any_variable_name | * }} variable name in between double curly bracket and wrap tag. I want to wrap those curly bracket which have variable name and if it is already wrap by my_wrap_tag than no need to wrap it

Comment: $subject has html template

Comment: If `$subject` is an HTML template, then I presume it is on server side. 
So, you will have to add these opening and closing tags manually. It doesn't make sense to edit these templates programmatically.

Comment: I made shopify app I don't know who use this app but when he/she install my app that time i need to change them template to display my app data on his site that's why i need to change programatically

Comment: Ok, but I am sure there will be other ways to do it. The best I can help you with is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265070/how-can-my-app-modify-the-shops-template-files) and [Shopify forums](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/programatically-update-product-liquid-on-app-install-401977)